# How can I get the width and length of a Picture in a Timage Component in Delphi Firemonkey

Tags: delphi, bitmap, firemonkey, delphi-11-alexandria, timage

I'm using Delphi RAD Studio 11.3 with Firemonkey. When I place a TImage component on a form and load a picture into it, the bitmap is automatically resized to fit the TImage component. That's perfectly fine. What I'm trying to find out is how to obtain the width and height of the currently displayed image. I don't want the width and height of the TImage component itself (e.g., Image1.Width or Image1.Height), nor do I need the dimensions of the original image (e.g., Image1.Bitmap.Width or Image1.Bitmap.Height).

What I'm looking for is the width and height of the image as it's currently displayed on the TImage component. Having this information will allow me to calculate the X and Y coordinates based on a MouseMove event on the displayed image, and from there, I can derive the corresponding points on the underlying bitmap.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Isn't the size of the resized picture equal to the size of the TImage component, since it resizes to fill it?

Comment: @Ineffable21 The default `wrapMode` is `Fit`, which indeed resizes, but proportionally. If width / height ratio of the `TImage` and the loaded picture are not the same, the picture will not fill the `TImage` completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to calculate the extents of the visual area based on several properties. In addition to `Position` and `Rotation` (if applicable) of the `TImage` component, consider at least the following:

1. The image size you have loaded into the `TImage` (might get stretched/shrunken to fit)
2. `WrapMode` setting (default is `Fit`, which stretches/shrinks proprtionally)
3. `Size` (or `Width` and `Height` seprately) of the `TImage`
4. `Scale` (horizontally and vertcally  separately) of the `TImage`

Comment: thank you for the hints. It's important to note that setting the WrapMode to "Fit" ensures that the Scale is always 1. You can determine the actual Width or Height of the "Inner Image" by comparing the Bitmap Ratio and the TImage Ratio. Depending on which one is larger, you can calculate the unknown side length by using the proportional side length of the inner Bitmap.